pytest using PyQt - Windows fatal exception: code 0x8001010d
This relates to pytest - Windows fatal exception: code 0x8001010d but i narrowed the error down to the simplest program.
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

q_app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

def test_widget():
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.show()
    q_app.processEvents()

Running test_widget with pytest passes, but it also displays a Windows fatal exception: code 0x8001010d on the line q_app.processEvents().
The answer in pytest - Windows fatal exception: code 0x8001010d recommends to ignore the error display using faulthandler.disable(), but rather than ignoring the error, can't we understand and avoid it?!
I am using python 3.9.12, PyQt5 5.15.7 and latest pytest 8.2.1.
Edit: ChatGPT is suggesting to use qtbot.wait instead of q_app.processEvents (qtbot is a fixture of library pytest-qt), but this does not solve my problem because, in my actual application, q_app.processEvents is inside the main program i want to test, so i can't use qtbot there.
